# Ionic 'build –prod" fails when InjectionToken is being used as dependency

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, build

First, it’s a part of providers array in my module:

```
const MyDepServiceInjectionToken = new InjectionToken('comment', {
  providedIn: 'root',
  factory: myDepServiceFactory,
});

...

providers: [{
multi: true,
  deps: [MyDepServiceInjectionToken],
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: HttpResponseInterceptor,
}],
```

And I can’t figure out why, but if I just use MyDepService class instead of injection token, everything is fine - project builds correctly. On the other hand, if I use Injection token with service-factory function *ionic build --prod* fails with error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError[InjectionToken HTTP_INTERCEPTORS -> function(){return{ngModule:t,providers:[{multi:!0,deps:[fr.a],provide:Ve.a,useClass:dr},{multi:!0,deps:[vr],provide:Ve.a,useClass:mr}]}}]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[InjectionToken HTTP_INTERCEPTORS -> function(){return{ngModule:t,providers:[{multi:!0,deps:[fr.a],provide:Ve.a,useClass:dr},{multi:!0,deps:[vr],provide:Ve.a,useClass:mr}]}}]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for function(){return{ngModule:t,providers:[{multi:!0,deps:[fr.a],provide:Ve.a,useClass:dr},{multi:!0,deps:[vr],provide:Ve.a,useClass:mr}]}}!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError[InjectionToken HTTP_INTERCEPTORS -> function(){return{ngModule:t,providers:[{multi:!0,deps:[fr.a],provide:Ve.a,useClass:dr},{multi:!0,deps:[vr],provide:Ve.a,useClass:mr}]}}]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[InjectionToken HTTP_INTERCEPTORS -> function(){return{ngModule:t,providers:[{multi:!0,deps:[fr.a],provide:Ve.a,useClass:dr},{multi:!0,deps:[vr],provide:Ve.a,useClass:mr}]}}]: (...)
```

Where can be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

The correct format for creating a dependency token is. I don't know if the constructor can be omitted like your code does.

```
const MY_SERVICE_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<MyService>('Manually constructed MyService', {
  providedIn: 'root',
  factory: myDepServiceFactory,
});
```

Comment: Uh, sorry. I've cleaned the example code of types and other things and forgot about class constructor. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing the code on the device or on the browser? I think browser does not support TOKENS. It's a service that can only be used on device

Comment: I'm trying to build it first (ionic build --prod) without errors ;-)

Comment: oh, ok. So that's the build... I'm using tokens, and it gives me error when using on the browser... Sorry for that then